# C# Cannot bind to the property or column on the DataSource

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 2 entities:

```
public class Address
{
    public string Street, City, State;
}

public class Customer
{
    public int Id;
    public string Name;
    public Address Address;
}
```

I have a WinForms form with 1 Textbox for the customer name and 1 usercontrol for the address. The user control has 3 textboxes for each address property. The form has a 'customer' bindingsource and the usercontrol an 'address' bindingsource. The user control looks something like this:

```
[DefaultBindingProperty("Address")]
public partial class AddressBox : UserControl
{
    private Address address;

    [Bindable(BindableSupport.Yes, BindingDirection.TwoWay)]
    [Browsable(false)]
    public Address Address
    {
        get { return address; }
        set
        {
            address = value;
            bindingSource.DataSource = address;
        }
    }
}
```

In deisgn mode, I set the datamembers of the form and the user control. However, once I set the datamembers of the address usercontrol, I getthe above error and can't open the form in design mode.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 3):

***To fix the design time error*** I removed all binding source creation, data source assignment and control data binding additions from the constructors and InitializeComponent of both form and user control, and wrap all that in a method, calling it:

1. in the user control: when handling OnLoad & VisibleChanged.
2. in the main form: when overriding OnShown.

In this particular master-child binding, the child user control fails when called from main form load since all wires have been set up, but no data assigned to it yet...

**Regarding the actual implementation**:
I guess there might be a more elegant way to do this using attributes. My way is this:

1. You have to transform public fields to public properties on the entity classes.
2. Wrap the address binding source methods in the address user control.

Sample screenshot, 'next' advances binding source position, looping on end:

[image: next advances binding source position, looping on end]

**Complete implementation below**:

1. [AddressUserControl](http://1drv.ms/1w88AwY)
2. [Form](http://1drv.ms/1w26rlq)
3. [Entities](http://1drv.ms/1w26m1l)

Comment: This is nearly the same as what I'm doing. However I still get the above error.